# How to use OVRInput in a custom DLL for unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dllimport, oculus

I working on Oculus using Unity. Initially I created a script in unity which directly and used the OVRInput for reading inputs. It's working fine.

Now, I wanted to create a DLL of that script.

I followed these steps to do it.(Please do suggest me if there are easier ways of doing it)

1. Created a Class Library project in VS2019.
2. Added UnityEngine.dll as a reference.

I am able to use all Unity related functions now. But VS isn't recognising OVRInput because I haven't added any references corresponding to it.
Adding the reference to OVRInput is my problem. I'm not sure how to do it.

What should I do if I want VS to recognise OVRInput? Is it possible to do so in the first place?

If it's not possible, is there any alternative way of creating the above dll?

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click on the **References** or **Dependencies**node and choose `Add Reference`. You can also right-click on the project node and select Add > Reference.

   Reference Manager opens and lists the available references by group.
2. Specify the references to add, and then select OK.

If you can't find the referenced DLL, set its `Copy Local` property to `true`.

Another way around is to set your [Reference Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y13ka7c(v=vs.90).aspx). This will force, on compile-time, your project to update itself with DLLs from the specified reference paths.

The best practice was to create a Shared folder where all referenced libraries were in so that you could write your reference paths once and for all per project.

I hope this helps, cheers!